# One thread changes BOOL to YES, another thread doesn't see change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, ipad, thread-safety

I have a property declared as the following:

```
@property(assign) BOOL die;
```

One thread continuously checks if it should die by looking to see if that variable has changed to YES. When that die is set to YES (by a user clicking a button), the other thread that is grinding away still sees it as NO. I've put careful traces through the code and seen that the variable definitely doesn't show up as modified. What is going on here?

Does each thread contain its own cache of the variable? In Java, my native language, I would have set the 'volatile' keyword on it to remove local thread caching on the property.

Is this something you can do in obj-c or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: Try posting the code where you access the variable.

Comment: And where you set the variable.

Comment: The method of continuously checking might be replaced by a wait or a notification, depending on what you are doing. We need code.

Comment: This code should work since the property is atomic by default. Something’s fishy with the way you’re accessing it.

Comment: How about "@property (assign) volatile BOOL die;" !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

different threads might be checking different instances. make sure that both threads are accessing to the same copy of that parameter

Answer (score -3):

You might be better using using notification centers, and so that the listener is notified when it is changed.